My program is supposed to compare test answers from a file, but it isn't registering blank answers. How do I fix this?
My program is reading from a file where the first line is the correct answers and the following lines contain the Student ID and their answers.
TTFTFTTTFTFTFFTTFTTF
ABC54102 T FTFTFTTTFTTFTTF TF
DEF56278 TTFTFTTTFTFTFFTTFTTF
ABC42366 TTFTFTTTFTFTFFTTF
ABC42586 TTTTFTTT TFTFFFTF

My code is supposed to compare the correct answers with the student's answers, deducting one point if the answer is wrong and two points if the answer is blank. I am very unfamiliar with C++ and am doing this for a class. The issue is my program isn't reading the blank spaces. My professor said to use a dummy char to read the spaces, but I don't understand what that means.
This is my full code:
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void gradingTool(const char correctAnswers[], const char studentAnswers[], int &score, char &grade) {
    score = 40;

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
        if (studentAnswers[i] == correctAnswers[i]) {
            
        } else if (studentAnswers[i] == ' ') {
            score -= 2; 
        } else {
            score -= 1; 
        }
    } 
    double percentage = (double(score) / 40) * 100;

    if (percentage >= 90) {
        grade = 'A';
    } else if (percentage >= 80) {
        grade = 'B';
    } else if (percentage >= 70) {
        grade = 'C';
    } else if (percentage >= 60) {
        grade = 'D';
    } else {
        grade = 'F';
    }
}

int main() {
    ifstream file("Ch8_Ex6Data.txt");
    if (!file) {
        cerr << "Error opening file!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    char correctAnswers[21];
    file.get(correctAnswers, 21); 

    file.ignore();

    char studentID[9];
    char studentAnswers[21]; 

    while (file.get(studentID, 9)) {
        file.ignore(); 

        file.get(studentAnswers, 21); 

        int answerLength = strlen(studentAnswers);
        if (answerLength < 20) {
            for (int i = answerLength; i < 20; ++i) {
                studentAnswers[i] = ' ';
            }
            studentAnswers[20] = '\0'; 
        }

        int score = 0;
        char grade = 'F';

        gradingTool(correctAnswers, studentAnswers, score, grade);
        
        
        cout << studentID << " " << studentAnswers << " " << score << " " << grade << endl;

        file.ignore(); 
    }

    file.close();
    return 0;
}

My output is
ABC54102 T FTFTFTTTFTTFTTF TF 33 B
DEF56278 TTFTFTTTFTFTFFTTFTTF 40 A
ABC42366 TTFTFTTTFTFTFFTTF    34 B
ABC42586 TTTTFTTT TFTFFFTF    30 C

But it is supposed to be
ABC54102 T FTFTFTTTFTTFTTF TF 27 D
DEF56278 TTFTFTTTFTFTFFTTFTTF 40 A
ABC42366 TTFTFTTTFTFTFFTTF    34 B
ABC42586 TTTTFTTT TFTFFFTF    26 D

I am absolutely wracking my brain with this

"This is my full code:" -- Your full code is undesirable. Instead, you should create a [mre]. Remove the parts that work. For example, if file.get(studentAnswers, 21); sets studentAnswers to the expected values, then skip the file. Start your main function with char studentAnswers[21] = "T FTFTFTTTFTTFTTF TF"; and see what else you can simplify away. On the other hand, if get() fails to set studentAnswers to the expected values, then skip everything after that (and simplify before it). Just output studentAnswers at that point, and tell us the expected and actual result of that.

Minor point -- there are three portable return values from main: EXIT_SUCCESS, EXIT_FAILURE, and 0. Returning 0 means success, but the value of EXIT_SUCCESS does not have to be 0. return 1; is not guaranteed to mean failure.

Recommendation: In the future step through your programs with the debugger that comes with your development tools get different tools if you somehow got a toolchain that's lacking a debugger). As you are stepping keep an eye out for the program doing something you didn't expect like storing the wrong value or taking the wrong path. The unexpected is either a bug or bad expectations. Either needs top be fixed before proceeding.

const char studentAnswers[] NO this is not "C", use std::string and std::string_view. Don't use "out arguments" (int &score, char &grade) but return a struct with two values. struct grading_result { int score; int grade; } and grading_result gradingTool(...)

Use std::string to contain the text and std::getline to read in the text.
To read in a player's ID:
std::string player_id;  
std::getline(my_file, player_id, ' '); // Read in until a space and eat the space.  
std::string scores;  
std::getline(my_file, scores);  // Read in remaining text, the scores.  

You can use std::string::length() to get the length of the string.  The string must be an exact length.
Also, you can use std::string::operator[] to access the individual character:
const unsigned int length = scores.length();  
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
{
    const char c = scores[i];
    if ((c != 't') && (c != 'f'))  // Edit: changed '||' to '&&'
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid score letter\n";
    }
}


Did you misspell 'T' and 'F' in that code?

if ((c != 't') || (c != 'f')) is always true; if ((c != 't') && (c != 'f')) (and fix the case) is what you want.

The scoring seems to be 2 points for a correct answer, -1 for incorrect, and zero for no answer, so in gradingTool() you need to subtract 3, not 1, for an incorrect answer, as you need to remove two points for not being correct, then one more for being wrong. Also, for future understandability it might be better to add points from zero rather than subtracting from 40.
Note: getline() then parsing the string would be better for the main loop as it allows you to use std::string throughout, but the file access code works as is.
Also, using namespace std; is generally not recommended.

Question says, "deducting one point if the answer is wrong and two points if the answer is blank".  I agree that's a strange scoring scheme (why would no answer score worse than simply guessing?) but that does appear to be closer to what's implemented - just missing -1 for not being correct, or as you say, better to count from zero rather than tying the code to the number of questions.

@TobySpeight Yes, it's a weird scoring system, but it's the only way to get the (presumably teacher-supplied) numbers in the question.


My output is ... But it is supposed to be ...

Why is the first student expected to get a D (67% correct) when their answers are 82% correct? A B makes more sense.
Same with the last student. Getting a C (75% correct) makes more sense than getting a D (65% correct).
Your code is actually processing correctly, based on the criteria provided. It is handling the scoring just fine, even the blank spaces. I think your expected output is wrong, not your actual output. You should talk to your teacher about this issue.
